# Why does deleting global and deleting var result in different outputs in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I went into Node in terminal and created a global user with global.user = {admin: false} . I also created an account var account = {balance: 1000} .
I then typed

```
delete user
=> true

delete account
=> false
```

Why does deleting something created globally return true, but deleting something created with var (which from my understanding is also global) return false?

[image]

Comment: both returns true in my case

Comment: i added an image so you know i'm not making a mistake

Comment: created both as global

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `delete` is for deleting properties of an object, not for deleting variables.  From MDN:

> The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object

And, in strict mode:

> var, let and const create non-configurable properties that cannot be deleted with the delete operator.  In strict mode this will raise a SyntaxError.

If you just try this in node.js in strict mode:

```
var x = "hello";
delete x;
```

You will get:

```
SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
```

In non-strict mode, the `delete` will return `false` and do nothing and will not throw an exception (for backwards compatibility reasons).

---

In node.js all your code is inside a module function so anything you declare with `var` is NOT a global.  It's a local variable inside the module function and local variables declared within a function cannot be removed with `delete` as that is not a feature that Javascript supports.  That's what `var` does - it creates a local variable in the current scope.

`global.user = xxx` assigns a property to the pre-existing `global` object which is predefined in the global scope.  Properties of the `global` object (like any other configurable properties of an object) can be removed with `delete`.

The `true` or `false` return value from the `delete` operator tells you whether the `delete` succeeded or not.

Comment: but then what's the difference between a local variable and a property of an object in that context? how is it even possible to have a property of a global object if defining anything occurs within the module function?

Comment: @Dog - `var account` creates a local variable in the current scope.  `global.user = xxx` assigns a property to the `global` object which is predefined in the global scope.  Those are very different things.  `delete` can be used to remove properties from the global object.  It cannot be used to remove things from the local scope as that is not a feature that Javascript supports.

Comment: @jfriend00 When you do `var user = "test"` in a single file nodejs program. You can do `console.log(global.test)` and it will give you `"test"`.  But when you do `delete global.test` it will return false. This means that you cant remove all properties using delete on global as mentioned in above comment

Comment: The reason for why this happens is mentioned in my answer to this question ^

Comment: @Atul - The middle part of your answer seems wrong to me.  And, when I do `var user = "test"` in a single file node.js program, `console.log(global.test)` gives me `undefined`, not the value of `test`.  `var user = "test"` makes a local variable for me, not a global variable.  And, if you look at the single file in the node.js debugger, you can see it is encapsulated within a module function which explains why `var test` makes a local variable, not a global one.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah yes !. It was working in node repl . Thanks for clearing it up. I will remove my answer and upvote urs. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope
>   or from a function's scope.

In case of failure to delete, the operation returns false.

Answer (score 1):

> The return value of delete is true for all cases except when the
>   property is an own non-configurable property, in which case, false is
>   returned in non-strict mode.

Also

> The delete operator removes a given property from an object. On
>   successful deletion, it will return true, else false will be returned.

Any property declared with `var` cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope and hence it returns `false`

Check the **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)** of delete

Answer (score 1):

you are deleting not an object property of `account`. but for case of user it goes to `global` object and deletes the `user` key from it. so if you try delete an undefined variable it show true.

```
> global.user = {1:2}
{ '1': 2 }
> delete user
true
> delete nice
true
> var account  = {3: 4}
undefined
> delete account 
false
> account
{ '3': 4 }
> global.user
undefined
> delete account['3']
true
> delete user
true
> nice = undefined
undefined
> delete nice
true
>
```